# Ni-Cd Battery discharge circuit model

Tags: resource-recommendations, physical-chemistry, batteries, electrochemistry

I am struggling with deriving a set of equations to represent mathematical model of Ni-Cd battery, so would you give me a through explanation and proper textbook/reference articles.

Answer (score 1):

NiCd cells are complicated physical systems, not simple mathematical abstractions. For the HETE-2 space mission, our power system engineer found it necessary to test cells of the exact type we intended to fly, under charge/discharge/thermal conditions similar to what we expected. He made an empirical model that he then used in his engineering calculations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good general battery modeling (not specific to NiCd) review article

[1]: Nihal Kularatna: Dynamics and Modeling of Rechargeable Batteries; December 2014, IEEE Power Electronics Magazine

Specific modeling that is really good and reliable will be difficult to find for it is likely be kept as trade secret but here is one publication from UMASS with test results:

[2]: Lynch, Salameh: Electrical Component Model for a Nickel-Cadmium Electric Vehicle Traction Battery; doi.org/10.1109/PES.2006.1709569

Comment: can you please give me reference Article/textbook for  Paatero,model of nickel cadmium battery?

Comment: I left out this reference https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224229196_Modeling_and_simulation_of_nickel-cadmium_batteries_during_discharge  because it talks about modeling discharge only but at its end is this  reference:  Paatero, “A mathematical model for ﬂooded nickel cadmium battery,” Helsinki University of Technology, Department of Physics, Tech. Rep., 1997 but unfortunately, but I do not have access to that.